# Multi-threading with WebRequest and StreamWriter in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, streamwriter

I need to make it work in threads for example, thread1 makes call to url with 'order_id=1' and thread2 makes call to url with 'order_id=2' and so on, and the result is then written into the file.

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub download()
    Dim address As String = "http://www.example.com/sales.php&order_id="
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\Folder\Licenses.txt"
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    Do While index <= 100
            If index > 100 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Try
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(address & index.ToString)
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()                
            If CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription = "OK" Then
                Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
                Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                If Not File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
                    Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(FILE_NAME)
                        sw.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
                        index += 1
                    End Using
                ElseIf File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
                    Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(FILE_NAME)
                        sw.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
                        index += 1
                    End Using
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need the output file ordered by id?

Comment: Not really. It should be saved in one file.

Comment: Please don't ever write `Catch ex As Exception` - especially with an empty catch block. Otherwise is appears that you're **trying** to write buggy code.

Comment: Also, `response`, `dataStream`, and `reader` all need to be disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach would be using `Parallel.For()`. You just have to make sure that you don't write different things to the output file at the same time. This is solved with the `Monitor`, which ensures that there will be only one thread in the critical section. Exception handling is omitted:

```
Dim address As String = "http://www.example.com/sales.php&order_id="
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\Folder\Licenses.txt"

Using fstream As New StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
    Parallel.For(0, 100, Sub(i As Integer)
                           Dim client As New WebClient
                           Dim content = client.DownloadString(address + i.ToString())
                           Monitor.Enter(fstream)
                           fstream.WriteLine(content)
                           Monitor.Exit(fstream)
                       End Sub)
End Using
```

This sample could be improved by creating the web clients as thread-local objects. This would avoid creating new clients for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a go at looking at Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this (NuGet "System.Reactive" or "Rx-Main" to get the bits).

Then you can do this:

```
Public Sub download()

    Dim address As String = "http://www.example.com/sales.php&order_id="
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\Folder\Licenses.txt"

    Dim download As Func(Of Integer, String) = _
        Function(n)
            Using wc As New WebClient()
                Return wc.DownloadString(New Uri(address & n.ToString()))
            End Using
        End Function

    Dim query = _
        From index In Observable.Range(0, 101) _
        From result In Observable.Start(Function () download(index))
        Select New With {.Index = index, .Result = result}

    Dim results = _
        query _
            .ToArray() _
            .Select(Function(xs) xs _
                .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Index) _
                .Select(Function(x) x.Result) _
                .ToArray())

    results.Do(Sub(lines) File.WriteAllLines(FILE_NAME, lines)).Wait()

End Sub
```

This will query each URL asynchronously and then perform a single file write when done.